# Dots on ceiling

Tags: ceiling, roof, mold

[image: dots]

In one of the rooms in my house, I have slanted ceiling. On the ceiling, some small dots can be seen. They run across the length of the slanted ceiling.

I am unsure what these marks could be. Any idea what they could be?

Comment: The photo is drastically underexposed. Can you post a brighter one? Looks like someone splattered grease on the paint.

Comment: That looks like something that got painted over and now it coming thru the paint.  If that the case, you'll need to paint with a kilz like product that seals it in, then put your top coat finish over that.  Like @isherwood said tho, post a better photo.

Comment: That could be mildew/mold, either old and "coming through" as Tyson mentions or in its initial growth stage. make sure you don't have a moisture issue before you do anything else. I painted a friends bathroom that had very similar marks, His original paint was flat (no sheen) and the bath was unventilated- it was mildew and I had to chemically kill it (with bleach) prior to priming and painting.

Comment: the the last homeowner get murdered in there?